# How to divide files in nginx location?

Tags: nginx

I serve statistic files by

```
location /files/ {
alias /folder1/;
}
```

Now I want to distribute the files in two disks. The `uri` has a format of `/files/[0-9]/subfolders/file.ext`. How can I configure nginx to read files from `/files/[0-4]/...` from Disk1, and `files/[5-9]/...` from Disk2. Note that `autoindex` is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can achieve this through regex matching. 
Add the following regexes:

```
location ~ "^/files/([0-4]/.*)$" {
    alias /disk1/files/$1;
}
location ~ "^/files/([5-9]/.*)$" {
    alias /disk2/files/$1;
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Please check updated answer.